# How to output "{}" in Rust

Tags: rust

I was wondering how to output closed brackets "{}" in Rust.

I've tried the following

- `println!("{}");`
- `println!('{}');`
- `println!(`{}`);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
println!("{{}}"); // 1
println!("{}", "{}"); // 2
```